# form input hidden field non required if controlled using hide/show condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In my form, I am using JavaScript to hide and show some fields by selection. It works perfectly but I want to require those fields only when these input fields will be shown, else it should be non-required. I have added required attribute in both the input fields, but when I select no and the input field is hidden, form submission doesn't works. after removing required attributes only it works.

```
<select name="tab" size="1" class="combo2" id="chkYes">

    <option value="">Select One</option>

    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>

</select>
```

Here below is the input fields that is shown based on the selection above.

```
<tr id="issuc" style="display:none;">
    <td><input name="country_issue" type="text" value="" required></td>
</tr>    
<tr id="ppno1" style="display:none;"><td>
    <input name="oth_ppt_no" type="text" value="" maxlength="26" size="43" required></td>
</tr>
```

This is the JavaScript that controls it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chkYes').on('change', function() {

    if ( this.value == 'Yes')

     {
      $("#issuc , #ppno1").show();
    } else {
      $("#issuc , #ppno1").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: good luck to you @user8879741

Comment: Well, you can change required attribute based on selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .prop function like this:

`$("#issuc input, #ppno1 input").prop("required", false)`

to remove the required attribute, and add it back by changing the 2nd parameter to true.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/euynpf0a/1/)

Comment: Thank Mate, It is Working Perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

put these in your if statement

```
$("#issuc , #ppno1").prop('required',true);

$("#issuc , #ppno1").prop('required',false);
```

Comment: No its Not Working Mate.

Comment: take a look at @jahl his works. I modified his coding to mine and that works too.

Comment: yes, yours worked too, i was doing some mistake, now its working perfectly.